# Make nested ng-repeat data scope specific to current item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm effectively trying to create a master-detail type view using two nested tables. The requirement is to view a list of summary records (master) and then "drill-down" into the details of that summary if desired. The details are to be displayed in a table beneath it's (master) summary record, but only if the user clicks on the button to view the details. We do not want to fetch all the details for all summaries on load of the page. Details' data must only be fesched via the Restful service and displayed when the summary record is clicked on.

I'm using AngularJs for the front-end with ASP.Net services on the back-end for data with a Restful interface.

My view looks like this (snippet):

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ProcessorId</th>
                <th>Processor</th>
                <th>Oldest</th>
                <th>Newest</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="summary in vm.summaries">
                <td>{{summary.ProcessorId}}</td>
                <td>{{summary.ProcessorDescription}}</td>
                <td>{{summary.OldestTransaction | date: vm.dateFmt}}</td>
                <td>{{summary.NewestTransaction | date: vm.dateFmt}}</td>
                <td>{{summary.QtyItemsInQueue}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                        <thead>
                        <tr><th>Meter</th><th>Amount</th><th>Requested</th><th>Session</th><th>Trxn No.</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.salesQueueDetails">
                            <td>{{item.MeterSerialNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.Amount}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.ReqDateTime | date: vm.dateFmt}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.SessionNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.TransactionNumber}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn" type="button" ng-click="vm.getSalesQueueDetail(summary.ProcessorId)">details for {{summary.ProcessorId}}</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

vm.summaries is loaded by the controller on startup, no problem there.

The problem comes in when I click on the details button to call  vm.getSalesQueueDetail for the selected Id. The resulting data is then repeated for every summary (master/parent) record and not just for the master record on which it was clicked.

How do I limit the binding of my details data only to it's corresponding summary (master/parent) record?

Comment: what resulting data and in what view? We don't know what `vm.getSalesQueueDetail()` does

Comment: The HTML snippet in my question is the view :-) And the AJS binding statements show you the structure of the data. You don't need the data or the detail of  vm.getSalesQueueDetail to answer. The latter just "gets the SalesQueue Detail" Data, as implied by the name. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second ng-repeat you should be assigning data to the current summary and not globally like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in summary.salesQueueDetails">
```

And then in your controller you should assign the details to the summary like:

```
$scope.getSalesQueueDetail = function(summary){
    ...after getting the data
    summary.salesQueueDetails = data;
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Gustavo,this was spot on! Thanks a lot!